# Three.js can't update object position/rotation

Tags: javascript, websocket, three.js

I'm trying to update object rotation and position after getting a socket message from server. Here's the code:

```
var enemies = {some, three.js, enemy, objects, here};
socket.on("tick", function(players)
{
    for(var i in players)
    {
        var player = players[i];
        if(player.ID !== myID)
        {
            enemies[player.ID].position.set(player.x, player.y, player.z);
            enemies[player.ID].rotation.set(player.rotX, player.rotY, player.rotZ);
        }
    }
});
```

Upon getting a "tick" message from server I just go through players object that I got from the server whose ID isn't the same as client player, then I update these players by setting their position and rotation but they don't seem to change, if I print to console in the if statement `console.log(enemies[player.ID]`, then I get the player that I want to update object, but I just can't update it, what could be the reason?

Comment: Can you check if the `matrixWorld` is getting updated after changing the position and rotation ? If not, then you can try setting `.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate` this property after updating the position and rotation for each enemy object.

Comment: Also be sure to call your renderer render() method if you not using a render loop.

Comment: @RasheduzzamanSourov The matrixWorld seems to be the same after every update.@Radio I'm rendering the game.

Comment: Then you have to add this line -  `enemies[player.ID].matrixWorldNeedsUp‌​date = true;` after updating the rotation,

   Check with it.

Comment: That doesn't help, my box is still stuck without rotating/changing position, though I can easily update other objects.

Comment: @RasheduzzamanSourov Sorry for your time found out my problem - it was updating all the time, though when I was testing it I was testing it fullscreen(haven't divided different clients so I can see both at the same time) and because of that when I changed the browser tab for some reason it would stop updating the player that is not on the tab that I'm on